# Async/Await Multi functions

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, async-await

I'am trying to make a simple application that loads data and performs an action on it. So my idea was to do this async.

I have 3 data sources and i would like to load them async. So for example Data1.xml, Data2.xml and Data3.xml all files are quite big to load so it takes some time (that's why i would like async).

So for example i made a window with 3 Textboxes that all bind to a specific property (Text1, Text2, Text3) and a button. When i click on the button i would like to execute 3 functions async (MakeText1,MakeText2, ...). I made MakeText3 the fastes one so normally i would have to see Text3 first. It doesn't work, what am i doing wrong?

```
private string _text1;

    public string Text1
    {
        get { return _text1; }
        set { _text1 = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text1"));
        }
    }

    private string _text2;

    public string Text2
    {
        get { return _text2; }
        set
        {
            _text2 = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text2"));
        }
    }

    private string _text3;

    public string Text3
    {
        get { return _text3; }
        set
        {
            _text3 = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text3"));
        }
    }

    public AsyncWin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private async Task MakeText1()
    {
        for (double i = 0; i < 7000000; i++)
        {
            _text1 = i.ToString();
        }
        Text1 = _text1;
    }
    private async Task MakeText2()
    {
        for (double i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
        {
            _text2 = i.ToString();
        }
        Text2 = _text2;
    }
    private async Task MakeText3()
    {
        for (double i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            _text3 = i.ToString();
        }
        Text3 = _text3;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _text1 = "";
        _text2 = "";
        _text3 = "";
        Test();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    public async void Test()
    {
        MakeText1();
        MakeText2();
        MakeText3();
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Xaml:

```
    <Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="181" Margin="10,19,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Text1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="181" Margin="137,19,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Text2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="181" Margin="276,19,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Text3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,219,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: All of your MakeTextN methods are synchronous. They run synchronously and then return a completed Task. If you want them to run on a background thread, you should use Task.Run

Comment: Thanks this works fine but is it possible with async ?

Comment: using the keyword `async` doesn't make the method asynchronous.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. But is there a way to do this with async/await?

Comment: Yes.  Use `Task.Run` for the non-UI work, `await` the returned `Task` and then update the UI element.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like that the UI show Text3 first than Text2

This does not happen in your code, because the artificial delay loops inside the setters for `Text1`..`Text3` runs synchronously, without letting other tasks having a go. If you replace these loops with `Task.Delay(...)`, you will get the desired effect:

```
private async Task MakeText1() {
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    Text1 = "3 seconds";
}
private async Task MakeText2() {
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Text2 = "2 seconds";
}
private async Task MakeText3() {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Text3 = "1 second";
}
```

Comment: Cannot return from a void method.

Comment: Yes but i would like that if MakeText3 is finished before the others, he show his data and not that i have to wait untill the others are finished.

Comment: I understand but i tried this and first of all the code gives errors. And i would like that the UI show Text3 first than Text2

Comment: Why are you explicitly calling `PropertyChanged` in `Test()`? Also, you're missing `await` before `Task.WhenAll()`.

Comment: @svick I added a call to `PropertyChanged` because OP sets the private variables that "back" the corresponding properties, instead of setting the properties themselves. I could have put `await` in front of `Task.WaitAll`, but I put it into `await Test();` instead. I ran this code locally, and it produced the desired effect.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's not `await` works. If you don't `await` the result of `WhenAll()` (not `WaitAll()`!), it will be simply ignored and there is no reason to call it in the first place. One way to observe that is if one of the `MakeTest` methods throws an exception, it will be silently ignored.

Comment: @svick Right, the `Task.WaitAll` is unnecessary in there. The only thing the OP has been missing was the way of making `async`-friendly delays. I removed everything unrelated to making OP's code work.